# Are there any integer solutions to f(x) = cos(x) besides (0,1)?

Tags: trigonometry, integers

I'm teaching a course that covers basic set theory and relations/functions.  We asked them to come up with a function from $\mathbf{N} \to \mathbf{N}$ that is neither one-to-one nor onto.

One of my students wrote down $f(x) = \cos(x)$ as their response.  Now, most likely they simply didn't understand the question and were simply desperately grabbing for points ($f(x) = \cos(x)$ is not even a function from $\mathbf{N} \to \mathbf{N}$ because, for example, $\cos(2)$ is not in the codomain).

However, it got me to thinking - are there any integers besides 0 that *do* have an integer image in the codomain of $f(x) = \cos(x)$?

Answer (score 5):

Actually, now that I think about this, there are only three possible integer values in the codomain: 0, 1, and -1.  The solution sets of $\cos(x) = 0$, $\cos(x) = 1$, and $\cos(x) = -1$ would all consist of non-integer (indeed, irrational) solutions apart from $\cos(0)=1$.

$\cos(x) = 1$:

$x = 2\pi k$, $k \in \mathbf{Z}$

$\cos(x) = 0$:

$x = \frac{\pi}{2} + \pi k = \pi(\frac{1}{2} + k)$, $k \in \mathbf{Z}$

$\cos(x) = -1$:

$x = \pi + 2\pi k = \pi(1 + 2k)$, $k \in \mathbf{Z}$

In all three cases (except for the first case when $k=0$), we have an irrational number times a rational number, which is irrational.

Comment: True because $\pi$ is irrational.  You can say more, that if $x\neq 0$ and $\cos(x)$ is rational then $x$ is transcendental, a consquence of the [Lindemann–Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem).

Comment: Yeah I was going to say, my explanation alone isn't satisfactory because it is possible to add two irrational numbers and get a rational number.

Comment: For your case you only have to note that nonzero rational times irrational is irrational, so $(k+\frac12)\pi$ is rational when $k\in\mathbb Z$ and $k\pi$ is rational when $k\in\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}$, if we can use that $\pi$ is irrational.

Comment: Ah yes you are correct, thank you.